# Exporting a Property Sheet in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, propertysheet

Sometimes when working on projects that people have posted online, I have to frantically modify my own property sheets to match theirs in order for my project to work (things like: MTd, linker stuff, Unicode/Multibyte settings).

I was wondering if I could just export a property sheet in Visual Studio for later use instead of creating one from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not if you use their project file, its settings are "last" and override anything you'd set in a project property sheet.

Nothing that you couldn't fix with a text editor btw, open the .vcproj or .vcxproj file with, say, Notepad to see how you could delete settings so a property sheet can work.  Or copy/paste settings from your own project file.